# Problem with Stationarity of time series in python

Tags: python, time-series

I have series with clearly visible upward trend and change in variance over time. When I tried `adfuller()` in python it is giving these results (`p<0.05`), so it is telling that series has no unit root basically stationary.

To see the data plot [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIONL.png)

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def adf_test(timeseries):
    #Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print ('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries)
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print (dfoutput) 

#apply adf test on the series
adf_test(df['Count'])
=====================================================
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                    -4.456561
p-value                            0.000235
#Lags Used                        45.000000
Number of Observations Used    18242.000000
Critical Value (1%)               -3.430709
Critical Value (5%)               -2.861698
Critical Value (10%)              -2.566854
dtype: float64
```

1. Should I agree with these results?
2. Do I need to do any further initial steps before checking for stationarity?

Comment: Isn't this more of statistical/econometric question rather than programming one?